# Remove duplicates from JSON file

Tags: json, bash, jq

My JSON file is very big so I won't show here all the data, but here's the example.

```
[ 
    { 
        "firstName": "C. Ronaldo",
        "lastName": "dos Santos Aveiro",
        "commonName": "Cristiano Ronaldo"
    }, 

    { 
        "firstName": "Luka",
        "lastName": "Modrić", 
        "commonName": ""
    }, 

    { 
        "firstName": "C. Ronaldo", 
        "lastName": "dos Santos Aveiro", 
        "commonName": "Cristiano Ronaldo"
    }
]
```

What I want to achive is to remove duplicated players that have same values inside.

So I want to get a result like:

```
[ 
    { 
        "firstName": "C. Ronaldo",
        "lastName": "dos Santos Aveiro",
        "commonName": "Cristiano Ronaldo"
    }, 

    { 
        "firstName": "Luka",
        "lastName": "Modrić", 
        "commonName": ""
    }
]
```

Thx in advance :)

Comment: actually, after reviewing, the `jtc` solution is even simpler for the given ask: `jtc -w'><Q:' -pf file.json `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `unique`.

```
$ jq 'unique' file
[
  {
    "firstName": "Luka",
    "lastName": "Modrić",
    "commonName": ""
  },
  {
    "firstName": "C. Ronaldo",
    "lastName": "dos Santos Aveiro",
    "commonName": "Cristiano Ronaldo"
  }
]
```